# Spring AMQP ListenerContainer lifecycle management

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We are using Spring AMQP to connect to RabbitMQ in our Spring based web application.

When we declare our listener-containers as beans (using `rabbit:listener-container`) in application context, their lifecycle is managed by Spring.

If we declare a listener-container in a component inside a `@PostConstruct` method, or we create a bean with class `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer` as a prototype scoped bean, we then have to manage the lifecycle i.e. start and stop the listener-container ourselves.

My question is, if we declare new queues, bindings and listener-containers inside a `@PostConstruct` method, just calling `listener.stop/shutdown/destroy` method inside the corresponding `@PreDestroy` method would be enough for a graceful shutdown? Or else what do I need to do?

Note: I am guessing I don't have to do anything for the new queues and bindings created in the `@PostContruct`, but I would be very glad if you also confirm this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend starting a listener container or declaring queues/bindings in an `@PostConstruct` method; the context is only half-baked at that time. It might work but it's not recommended to do stuff like that while the context is being initialized.

It's better to implement `SmartLifecycle` and start/stop them in the `start()/stop()` methods.

Then, the container lifecycles would be indirectly managed by the spring context.

You can also control exactly when your bean is started/stopped by putting it in a phase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will implement `SmartLifecycle` interface instead of using `@Postconstruct/@PreDestroy`. Also, just calling `stop` on the listener-container will clean up everything gracefully, right? And nothing to be done for queues and bindings?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by clean up. If you declare the queue/exchange as auto-delete, they will disappear automatically when the container stops; the queue is deleted first; the exchange is deleted when there are no queues. If you want them to remain between invocations (to avoid losing messages), there is no clean up to do; declaring them next time will be idempotent and you will pick up any messages remaining from the last invocation. If you don't declare them auto-delete and you want them to go away then you will need to delete them (e.g. using RabbitAmin) after stopping the container.

Comment: Note that auto-delete can be problematic when you drop connections. Spring-declared queues etc are automatically re-declared when the connection is re-established. Since you are rolling your own for some reason, you will need to handle redeclaring auto-delete items after a connection failure. It's generally easier to just let Spring take care of things for you rather than doing it yourself.